# custom yeoman generator test: creating files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've got a very simple yeoman generator, [`watchjs`](https://github.com/ducin/generator-watchjs), that has `speaker` subgenerator. Below is hos it is used:

`$ yo watchjs:speaker
You called the watch.js speaker subgenerator.
? Speaker file: data/speakers/speakers.json
? Speaker name: abc
{ file: 'data/speakers/speakers.json', name: 'abc' }
Generated slug is: abc
Trying to add: {
    "id": "abc",
    "name": "abc"
}`

Mainly, there are two prompts: `file` - which defines the json file where data should be appended to and `name` - which defines actual data to be added to the file (slightly modified). I'm trying to write a simple yeoman test for this. I've been trying to follow [the docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html), but I'm failing all the time:

```
$ npm test

> generator-watchjs@0.0.2 test c:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Documents\GitHub\generator-watchjs
> mocha

  Watchjs:speaker
{ file: 'speakers.json', name: 'John Doe' } // <- this is my console.log
    1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (59ms)
  1 failing

  1) Watchjs:speaker "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\TOMASZ~1.DUC\AppData\Local\Temp\53dac48785ddecb6dabba402eeb04f91e322f844\speakers.json'
      at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
      at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
      at module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.writing (c:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Documents\GitHub\generator-watchjs\speaker\index.js:43:33)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I can't understand where is the file actually created and where are the tests looking for it... There seems to be used a temporary windows location, but anyway, if all things work properly relative to the path, the file should have been found and it's not. Can't figure out what to do to make tests pass.

The best content of my test file is:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var assert = require('yeoman-generator').assert;
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;

describe('watchjs:speaker', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../speaker'))
      .withOptions({ 'skip-install': true })
      .withPrompts({ 'file': 'speakers.json', 'name': "John Doe" })
      .on('end', done);
  });

  it('creates files', function () {
    assert.file([
      'speakers.json'
    ]);
  });
});
```

I'm passing a specific `name` and `file` name via prompt.

I've found out that `npm test` call package.json's `mocha` command (and that's it). But I'm not an expert in mocha.

I'm using node v0.10.35 on Windows7.

Comment: As you mentioned, in your test your passing a specific file (i.e. "speakers.json"). Before I post my answer, I would like to ask: "Where is that file?"

Comment: Based on [this line](https://github.com/ducin/generator-watchjs/blob/master/speaker/index.js#L42) in your generator, it seems it expects the file to already exist. Is this this the case?

Comment: In the beginning, I've got no file. The subgenerator creates the file and I want to test that it gets created. That's all. Maybe I made something wrong, probably yes. But, as far as I understand the code, the `before` section prepares the environment before the tests are actually run. So if the generator gets called before, then the file should be created already.

Comment: Okay. Then I have two observations. (1) your `:speaker` sub generator is not creating the file, and (2) you need to use absolute paths in your test. I will compose my recommendations in an answer shortly.

Comment: FYI ... I submitted a PR ([#1](https://github.com/ducin/generator-watchjs/pull/1)) to your repo with my proposed fix. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use absolute paths in your test, so the location of the file is predictable.

My test would look something like this:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var assert = require('yeoman-generator').assert;
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;

describe('watchjs:speaker', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    var self = this;
    var name = 'John Doe';
    var testPath = path.join(__dirname, 'temp');

    // store in test obejct for later use
    this.filePath = path.join(testPath, 'speaker.json');

    helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../speaker'))
      .inDir(testPath)
      .withPrompts({ 'file': self.filePath, 'name': name })
      .withOptions({ 'skip-install': true })
      .on('end', done);
  });

  it('creates files', function () {
    assert.file(this.filePath);
    assert.fileContent(this.filePath, /\"id\":.*\"john-doe\"/);
    assert.fileContent(this.filePath, /\"name\":.*\"John Doe\"/);
  });

});
```

Second, and not directly related to your question, the test above will on the code in the repo you shared. Like I mentioned in my comment, it throws an error [here](https://github.com/ducin/generator-watchjs/blob/master/speaker/index.js#L42) if the file doesn't already exist.

I would change:

```
var content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this.options.file, 'utf8'));
```

to:

```
try {
  var content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this.options.file, 'utf8'));
} catch(e) {
  content = [];
}
```

With the change above, the test will pass.

Comment: just to let you know, you don't need to readFile a json file.  U can just `require` it and then use it.